# Using regex replace a string with the same string with quotes (") removed using php

Tags: php, regex

I have a multi-line string shown below -

```
   ?a="text1
    ?bc="text23
```

I need to identify a pattern like using below regex

```
  '/[?][a-z^A-Z]+[=]["]/'
```

and replace my string by just remove the double quote (") in it, expected output is shown below

```
?a=text1
?b=text23
```

Please help in solving the above issue using php.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I need to retain the same found string just to replace the double quote

Comment: `=` and `"` are not reserved characters in regex, the don't need to be character classed.

Comment: If the goal is to just remove whitespace and double quotes `str_replace` and `trim` are probably easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture everything except the quote in a capture group `()` and replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([?][a-z^A-Z]+[=])["]/', '$1', $string);
```

But you really don't need all those character classes `[]`:

```
/(\?[a-z^A-Z]+=)"/
```

Comment: It's not stated in the question but the first parameter seems to need to be trimmed to 1 character. .e.g `bc` became `b` (or it is just a typo)

Comment: We'll see, I just saw _replace my string by just remove the double quote (") in it_

Answer (score 0):

I will give another solution because i see the php tag also. So let's say you have these:

```
$a='"text1';
$b='"text2';
```

if i echo them i get

```
"text1
"text2
```

in order to get rid of double quote there is a function trim in php that you can use like that:

```
echo trim($a,'"');
echo trim($b,'"');
```

the results will be

```
text1
text2
```

I dont think you need regex in this occasion as long as you use php. Php can take care of those small things without bother with complex regex expressions.